# Date Without Time Using C# and InsertParameters (ASP.NET)

Tags: c#, asp.net, date

I use this C# code in ASP.NET to display date without time in GridView through "AccessDataSource":

```
var f = DateTime.Now;
string dwt = f.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");

AccessDataSource3.InsertParameters["Date birth"].DefaultValue = dwt;
AccessDataSource3.Insert();
```

But still, the application displays date like this: `dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss`.

I also tried this:

```
string f = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy");
string[] v = f.Split(new char[] { ' ' });

AccessDataSource3.InsertParameters["Date birth"].DefaultValue = ""+v[0];
AccessDataSource3.Insert();
```

Doesn't work either.
Maybe these codes don't work because I have forgot to add something into them?

Comment: `String.Format("{0:dd/MM/YYYY}",DateTime.Now)` should work.

Comment: Is `Date birth` a `datetime` column in access?

Comment: Yes, it is, but I need to use C# instead of SQL-query

Comment: Speaking of String.Format - should I write down the code like this?

`var f = DateTime.Now; <br/>
string dwt = f.ToShortDateString();<br/>
String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", f);`

Answer (score 0):

Try `ToShortDateString()` method

```
var f = DateTime.Now;
string dwt = f.ToShortDateString();
```

This will only result in `date` like `17/06/2016`

Comment: The poster is already trimming off the time part of the string and saying it is still not working.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your data source has the 'Date birth' field set as a DateTime type and when you assign your string to it a cast is taking place.

Have you tried setting the format of the field in your GridView like this:

```
<asp:boundfield datafield="Date Birth"
        DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/YYYY}"
        headertext="D.O.B"/>
```

Comment: Yes, but I need an alternative path to format date, using C#

Comment: You will need to set the field in your data source to have a type of string rather than DateTime then. Otherwise you are writing code like this DateTime t = (DateTime)(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/mm/yyyy")).